# PyInstaller over different linux distroes

Tags: python, linux, pyinstaller

Can you use pyinstaller to build a binary and use it over different linux distributions?

I am facing an issue when running the binary on a different distribution than the one the binary was built on. At some point the program crashed with:

```
python3: undefined symbol: _Py_LegacyLocaleDetected
```

These two linux distributions have different patch versions(3.6.X)

Anybody has any idea of what I could do to get it working?